Как вывести на консоль день, месяц и год
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.today()

ask = "да"
while ask.lower() == "да" :
    try:
        print(d1.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"))
        print("-------------------")
        task = input("Что нужно сделать?" )
        dak = int(input("Через сколько нужно сдать?" ))
        if dak >= 4 :
            print("Всё хорошо")
        elif dak < 4 and dak > 0:
            print("Ты не успеешь")
        elif dak <= 0:
            print("Уже поздно...")
        d1 = datetime.datetime.today()
        d2 = datetime.timedelta(days = dak )
        print("Сдай работу до", d1 + d2)
        print("---------------------------")
    except ValueError:
        print("Напиши нормальные цифры")
    ask = input("Хотите ещё внести задачу?" )

Я хочу чтобы код выводил только год, месяц и число

Я так понимаю, что код, мягко говоря, не совсем авторский. Потому что ответ содержится в вопросе: есть d1.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"), хотя и написанный плохенько, надо d1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
Очевидно, что ответ надо писать аналогично:
print("Сдай работу до", (d1 + d2).strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))


Учитесь читать документацию. Если в том же формате, что и ввод был, то так же и форматируете через f-строку:
print(f'{d1+d2:%Y.%m.%d}')

